# requireGestureRecognizerToFail do not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using two different TapGestureRecognizer to handle both single and double tap on screen.
This is the code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [tapGR setDelegate:self];
    [tapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [doubleTapGR setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGR];

    [tapGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail : doubleTapGR];

    [tapGR release];
    [doubleTapGR release];
```

Even if I specified that [tapGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTapGR] the "handleTap" selector is performed. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made a mistake! You used `setNumberOfTouchesRequired` method for `doubleTapGR` instead of using `setNumberOfTapsRequired`. Here is the corrected code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[tapGR setDelegate:self];
[tapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];


UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[doubleTapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGR];

[tapGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail : doubleTapGR];

[tapGR release];
[doubleTapGR release];
```

Best regards ;)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong if I have slight delay when I just single tap?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have omitted:

```
[doubleTapGR setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I self answered my question, sorry, I'm really dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I really am dumb :)

I wrote:

```
[doubleTapGR setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
```

Instead of:

```
[doubleTapGR setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
```

Feel free to delete this answer. Sorry StackOverflow.